# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var tmp = productDBSet.Where(x => x.lastUpdate >= DateTime.MinValue && x.lastUpdate.Value.ToString("MM/yyyy") == curMonth).Select(x => x.ID);
```

While I run above code, I got this error message:

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.*

Also I tried,

```
var tmp = productDBSet.Where(x => x.lastUpdate >= DateTime.MinValue && x.lastUpdate.Value.ToString("MM/yyyy") == curMonth).ToList().Select(x => x.ID);
```

But same,

How can I solve that?

Comment: Instead of doing a `ToString()` on `lastUpdate`, convert `curMonth` to a `DateTime` you can use to compare against `lastUpdate` directly.

Comment: instead of '==' use .Equals()

Comment: @Rex There's nothing wrong with using `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, the `ToString` method of `DateTime` isn't supported.

Since you're just trying to determine if the month and year of the date match a given value, you can just compare the actual month and year, rather than trying to get a string containing the month and year that you compare with.

```
x.lastUpdate.Value.Year == yearToCompareWith && 
    x.lastUpdate.Value.Month = monthToCompareWith
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use ToString() in Linq to Entities. Try something like this (I've assumed that x.lastUpdate is of type "DateTime"):

```
x.lastUpdate.Month == curMonth && x.lastUpdate.Year == curYear
```

This happens, because LINQ to Entities is translated to SQL queries, and therefore method ToString is not recognised.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use extension methods in linq queries, since these are unable to get converted to equivalent Sql Queries. You can use following linq:

```
var tmp = productDBSet.Where(x => x.lastUpdate >= DateTime.MinValue && x.lastUpdate.Month == curMonth && x.lastUpdate.Year == curYear).Select(x => x.ID);
```